# What is the near point (punctum proximum) of cats?

Tags: cats, vision, anatomy

Or, in other words, how close a cat can see distinctively ?

For instance, it is around 25cm for an average 46 year old human.

As a reference, there are relevant articles on Wikipedia:

- [in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_distance_of_distinct_vision);
- [in French](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punctum_proximum).

definition: https://www.biologyonline.com/dictionary/punctum-proximum

Comment: i do not belive this question can be answered as it is now,a cats eyesight changes over time in the same way as it does in people and it does not happen at the same pace for all cats or people.my 14 years old cat can not see objects closer than 30-40CM clearly but when she was 2-3 years old she could not see objects closer than 10-20 CM clearly so she is getting more farsighted over the years.

Comment: like human..., I never said it won't change over the course of the cat life, but maybe there are some research with nice chart with "cat age" along x axis and "punctum proximum" along the y axis...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I believe it belongs on a science stack exchange instead.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [research](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0042698977800102?via%3Dihub) seems to be 12cm.

> Determined the near point of accommodation in 4 cats by measuring visual acuity at viewing distances varying from 125 to 12 cm. The near point of accommodation was taken as the closest viewing distance which just produced a decrement in grating acuity. Results show that the values obtained ranged from 25 to 36 cm and are in good agreement with physiological and optical estimates of the near point of accommodation. (24 ref) (PsycINFO Database Record (c) 2016 APA, all rights reserved)

ref:
Visual acuity and the near point of accommodation in cats.
Bloom, M., & Berkley, M. A. (1977). Visual acuity and the near point of accommodation in cats. Vision Research, 17(6), 723–730.

Comment: also be interested on Visual resolution in young kittens
https://psycnet.apa.org/record/1977-00468-001